# CloudFormation - not able to create Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I am trying to create a Lambda Function and Lambda TriggeronSQS. Following is my cloud Formation template -

## Template

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Resources": {
    "myfunction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Runtime": "java8",
            "Role": "arn:aws:iam::219560220147:role/test@123",
            "Code": {
                "S3Bucket": "lambdacode1234",
                "S3Key": "code.jar"
            },
            "MemorySize": 256,
            "Handler": "com.test.MyHandler",
            "Timeout": 25
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "63dae6c8-ebdb-459b-88db-02ad5dae294a"
            }
        }
    },
    "LESM34AJN": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping",
        "Properties": {
            "EventSourceArn":"  arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:219560220147:testlambda",
            "FunctionName": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "myfunction",
            "Arn"
        ]
    },
            "BatchSize" : 1,
            "Enabled" : "TRUE"
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "26a65289-5f1e-41db-b94d-812d2340c945"
            }
        }
    }
},
"Mappings": {
    "RegionCodeMapping": {
        "us-east-1": {
            "regionCode": "US"
        },
        "us-west-2": {
            "regionCode": "FE"
        },
        "eu-west-1": {
            "regionCode": "EU"
        }
    }
},
"Parameters": {
    "teamname": {
        "Description": "Enter Name TeamName",
        "Type": "String",
        "AllowedPattern": "^[a-z0-9-]*$"
    },
    "env": {
        "Description": "Enter Envirment type e.g. dev,test,prod",
        "Type": "String",
        "AllowedValues": [
            "devo",
            "test",
            "prod"
        ]
    },
    "sqsARNtoTriggerLambda": {
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "codeFile": {
        "Type": "String"
    }
},
"Outputs": {
    "LambdaFunctionARN": {
        "Description": "ARN of Lambda Function",
        "Value": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "myfunction",
                "Arn"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

## ERROR

I tried creating stack via AWS Console, but receiving below error for SQS policy creation

> 1 validation error detected: Value ' arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:219560220147:testlambda' at 'eventSourceArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z0-9-]*):([a-zA-Z0-9-])+:([a-z]{2}((-gov)|(-iso(b?)))?-[a-z]+-\d{1})?:(\d{12})?:(.*) (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 9a86cb1e-49e4-490d-9e48-fd93aa8d81dd)

[CloudFormation Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RkHk.png)

I have referred the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html)  but can't figure out what the problem is? Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove spaces from `EventSourceArn`.

Change

```
"LESM34AJN": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping",
    "Properties": {
        "EventSourceArn":"  arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:219560220147:testlambda",
        "FunctionName": {
    "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "myfunction",
        "Arn"
    ]
},
```

To

```
"LESM34AJN": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping",
    "Properties": {
        "EventSourceArn":"arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:219560220147:testlambda",
        "FunctionName": {
    "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "myfunction",
        "Arn"
    ]
},
```

[image]

[From here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html)